# Perl Array Output Not Consistant

Tags: linux, perl

So I'm writing this Perl script to list the contents of a folder and grepping a specific file.  When I run my script, files with single digit dates don't work correctly.

```
foreach $device (@devices){
   $ls = `ls -l /mypath/to/$device | grep '.confg'`;
        @lsOut = split / /, $ls;
        if (@lsOut){
                print $lsOut[5] . ' ' . $lsOut[6] . ' ' . $lsOut[7];
        }

}
```

Here is the current output

```
Jul 29 09:35
Jul 29 09:47
Aug  6
Aug  6
Jul 29 07:32
Jul 29 09:51
Jul 29 09:25
Aug  6
Aug  6
```

Those Aug 6th dates should also have the time stamp on them.

Comment: You are splitting on a single space, not on a group of spaces. Thus, you are getting an additional empty field between each pair of spaces. As it happens, `Aug⋅⋅6` has one space more than `Jul⋅29`, so `6` ends up in `$lsOut[7]`. Use `/\s+/` instead.

Comment: @Amadan Thank you so much!  It worked!

Comment: There is a difference between `split ' '` and `split / /`. See `perldoc -f split`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the manpage on [`split`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html). You are splitting on a single space - a common problem with what you're doing is if the text in `Aug  6` is aligned, it'll have two spaces in it, thus you'll get an undesired 'null' field.

`split` does some subtly different things depending how you specify 'space'. E.g.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

my $example_str = "    some text   here Aug  6 Jul 27";

my @stuff = split ( / /, $example_str );
print Dumper \@stuff; 

my @stuff2 = split ( /\s+/, $example_str );
print Dumper \@stuff2; 

my @stuff3 = split ( ' ', $example_str );
print Dumper \@stuff3;
```

This gives:

```
$VAR1 = [
          '',
          '',
          '',
          '',
          'some',
          'text',
          '',
          '',
          'here',
          'Aug',
          '',
          '6',
          'Jul',
          '27'
        ];
$VAR1 = [
          '',
          'some',
          'text',
          'here',
          'Aug',
          '6',
          'Jul',
          '27'
        ];
$VAR1 = [
          'some',
          'text',
          'here',
          'Aug',
          '6',
          'Jul',
          '27'
        ];
```

Splitting on `/ /` gives you more fields, but has a bunch of zero length strings. Splitting on `/\s+/` gives you almost what you want, but note - it treats 'start of line' as a field (so you get an empty one). And `' '` gives you whitespace delimited starting from the first character. This is *generally* what you're going to want, which is why it's the default when you just `split;`